# $\tan x=\frac{x}{\cos^2 x}$

Tags: trigonometry

$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{\alpha}{\cos^2(\alpha)}$

I do not find the connection.
It is part of a task, but i do not see how it would be a general thing.
I am not sure how to approach it.
Also I don't kn ow, is it only working for a/that specific szenario or is it a general thing? (Perhabs the latter would be the case anyway)

I other words: How can I show this?
$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{\alpha}{\cos^2(\alpha)}$

I thought of exchanging $\frac{\alpha}{\cos^2(\alpha)}$
with $\alpha(1 + \tan^2(\alpha))$ [edited after correction in the comments], getting a quadratic equation and substituting... but that didn't help at all.

I tried different approaches of using $\tan(\alpha) = \frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)}$. Didn't do it.

I am somewhat confused by the isolated $\alpha$. It makes me think that I might have to use $\arctan$ or $\arccos$ at some point or at least get to some arcus-function on the way.

However it might also be that it is some kind of conclusion regarding the connected task and thus it might be difficult to prove it isolated. Be it so, this is likely to be the wrong forum to pose the question.

Therefore I want to know, if this equation looks familiar to you and/or if you know how to prove it or could give hints on in which direction I should move.

I hope not to cause inconvenience.

Sunny regards

Comment: You can't "show this" because it isn't true for all $\alpha$. You might be able to find specific $\alpha$ for which it is true, however.

Comment: $$\frac{\alpha}{\cos^2 \alpha}=\alpha\left(1+\tan^2\alpha\right)$$ You can't get rid of the $\alpha$ in the numerator.

Comment: If you multiply both sides by $\cos^2$, you get $\sin\alpha\cos\alpha = \alpha$.  An obvious solution is 0.

Comment: Equation can be transformed to $\sin(2\alpha)=2\alpha$. There is known and easy to obtain result that transcendental equation $\sin t = t$ has unique real solution $t=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Your equation is only true when $\alpha = 0.$

Answer (score 1):

From $\tan{x} = \frac{x}{\cos^2{x}}$ we get $\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}} = \frac{x}{\cos^2{x}}$ and therefore, $\sin{x}\cos{x} = x$. The LHS equals $\frac{1}{2}\sin{2x}$. So we must solve $\sin{2x} = 2x$.

Let $2x = u$ and $g(u) = \sin{u} - u$. Then $g'(u) = \cos{u} - 1 \leq 0$. So $g$ is a decreasing function anywhere and because $g(0) = \sin{0} - 0 = 0$, we conclude that the only root of $g(u)$ is $u = 2x = 0$. Therefore, the given equation only holds for $x = 0$.